# Titanium Alloy - cached image not appearing on imageView

Tags: ios, caching, imageview, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm using titanium alloy MVC framework for developing an app for both iOS and android. I've a tableView which is being populated by remote data(JSON). Its working perfectly, but I want to cache when there is isn't any internet connection available.

i'm caching the data using the following code:

```
function saveData(data){
   var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
   var fileDirectory = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'results.txt');
   fileDirectory.write(data);
}


function getData(){
   var fileDirectory = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'results.txt');
   var fileContents = fileDirectory.read();

   var receivedData = JSON.parse(fileContents.text);

   var parseReceivedData = JSON.parse(receivedData);
    for (i = 0; i < parseReceivedData.Photos.length; i++){


    var receivedPhotoTitle = parseReceivedData.Photos[i].title;
    var receivedCollectionName = parseReceivedData.Photos[i].category;
    var receivedCreatedAt = parseReceivedData.Photos[i].datetime;
    var receivedImageURL = url+"/media/files/"+parseReceivedData.Photos[i].photo;


    photoCollection.push(Alloy.createController('collectionRow',{"receivedImageURL":receivedImageURL,
                                                                 "receivedPhotoTitle":receivedPhotoTitle,
                                                                 "receivedCreatedAt": receivedCreatedAt,
                                                                 "receivedCollectionName": receivedCollectionName
                                                                 }).getView());
} // End of For Loop                                                            
}
```

I'm getting the correct URL for the image and also the text but when I assign it to my imageView and label it doesn't appear on the table and the table appears blank.

I'm executing the saveData() in onload function and getData in onerror function.

I'm working with remote data for the first time. So, if i'm doing anything wrong please help me correct it.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post your code for collectionRow.js and collectionRow.xml ?

Comment: @Nando no worries. I've done it using a different method.